# Random element from an array of images and their respective links on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I've got an unordered list of images. I'd like for each of those images to have an href attribute (since I would like to use a lightbox-popup to display the correlating image when clicked), but for each image to be random when the page is refreshed.

In short, for each image coupled with its href to be random, but the order of the ul to stay the same. What would be a way of achieving this?

Comment: Is your source / HTML hardcoded or do you source it from some kind of backend / CMS?

Comment: @m90 yeah, it's all handwritten html.

Comment: u mean order the images randomly ?

Comment: So if you're just looking for a way to link a `href` to a `li` you could use a `data`-attribute to store the `href`, shuffle the `li`s and call your lightbox?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Should've been more specific. I wouldn't want the li to be shuffled, but simply for each li image to be random on refresh. The li order would stay the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
var img_array = []; //assuming your array is called this and full of porn pictures

//fisher-yates algorithm. Google it
(function(){
    var tmp, current, top = img_array.length;
    if(top) while(--top) {
        current = Math.floor(Math.random() * (top + 1));
        tmp = img_array[current];
        img_array[current] = img_array[top];
        img_array[top] = tmp;
    }
})();

//target html element where the images are appended
var target = document.getElementById('someTargetDiv');

for(var i=0, len=img_array.length; i<len; i++){
    var link = document.createElement('a'),
        img = document.createElement('img');

    link.setAttribute('href', img_array[i]);
    img.setAttribute('src', img_array[i]);

    link.appendChild(img);
    target.appendChild(link);
}
```

This is not an optimized way of doing this kind of operation. I've made it slightly more verbose for your understanding.

The biggest mistake with this code is the constant creation of many different elements and appending them to the DOM one at a time. What should really be done is to build a string of generated html, and changing the innerHTML of a target div in one operation.

```
var html = [];
for(var i=0, len=img_array.length; i<len; i++){
    html.push('<a href="'+ img_array[i] +'"><img src="'+ img_array[i] +'"></a>');
}

target.innerHTML = html.join('');
```

Comment: Instead of making a string like you are in the last code block you could use a document fragment (http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) which gets around the issue you mention with creating and appending to the DOM while keeping it nice and readable.

Comment: Thor, I used to use and recommend the documentFragment approach too. However, in recent years optimizations in all major browsers have reduced the need for that technique greatly. Array concatenation and innerhtml is well supported in all browsers and is as fast or even faster than the technique that John described these days.

Comment: Whatever you prefer really, I wasn't thinking about speed as much as readability though.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I get this right.

With jQuery you could do it like [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xMJcH/1/):

```
$('ul').children('li').sort(function() {
    return Math.round(Math.random()); // randomly get 0 or 1
}).appendTo('ul');
```

Doing it with PHP on server side would make more sense, but since you have no db resource or so, you'd have to make a static array of image:link pairs then shuffle it and generate a random list.

**UPDATE**

Maybe this comes closer to a solution:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xMJcH/3/)

```
var contents = new Array(),
    $list = $('li');

$list.each(function() { contents.push($(this).children()); });

contents.sort(function() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
});

$list.each(function() {
    $(this).append(contents.shift());
});
```

Comment: While easy to read and understand, this sort is biased (http://javascript.about.com/library/blsort4.htm?rd=1) which is generally not desirable.

Comment: What do you mean by biased in this context?

Comment: Biased as in it won't have an even distribution. I've added a reference to the comment.

Comment: Yeah I know, I just deleted a comment to m90 about not as random as the Fisher Yates shuffle, but I think since it's not a case of scientific calculation here, one could disregard the tiny difference and go for the shorter code.

Comment: Yeah I'm not saying your answer is wrong or useless, just that anyone seeing the answer should be aware that there is a bias and that they may not want to use it based on that.

Comment: Digging the short code, nice. I know I really should've written my question better, but is there a way to randomize the individual <li> element rather than the order? I'm sorry, I'm not very good with javascript/jquery.

Comment: Yeah like I read from the other comments you want to just randomize the images? Working on a solution for that.